# C++ Xcode lldb error: loops never work

Tags: c++, xcode, lldb

thanks for taking the time to help me out.
I'm really new with C++ and Xcode.  I was working on a simple program to help me understand loops, so my goal was to make a simple "echo machine".  This is my code:

```
string words;

 int main()
{

do {
    cout << "Enter text.";
    cin >>  words;
    cout << "You entetered " << words << "!";
}

while (words != "goodbye");
return 0;
}
```

My result is nothing but lldb in parenthesis.  I am very frustrated and can't find what I'm doing wrong anywhere.  Please help and thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just missing the include directives for the standard headers you're using?
Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string words;
    do {
        cout << "Enter text: ";
        cin >> words;
        cout << "You entered " << words << "!\n";
    } while (words != "goodbye");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick.  Thanks so much!  For future reference, do you have to use the #include tag for each type of variable you enter?

Comment: Not exactly. Some types are built in (such as int, char, float, etc.). Others are in the standard library (such as string, vector, map, etc.). At this point I suggest you keep reading whatever book you're using.